# Why does free()-ing my memory malloc()-ed in another function cause a crash?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, free

I have a linked list of structures and functions to add, remove, and create data from/in it. Now the problem arises when I try to free() data that I have allocated in the create function. The program works fine if I remove the part of my code where I free my memory, but then I do not free the memory.

The struct:

```
typedef struct carinfo_t
{
    char * brand;
    char * model;
    int year;
    float value;
    struct carinfo_t * next;
} carinfo_t;
```

The function where I create the items that are to be added in the list:

```
struct carinfo_t *createCarinfo(char *brand, char *model, int year, float value)
{
    carinfo_t *newInfo = (carinfo_t *) malloc (sizeof(newInfo));
    newInfo->brand = malloc (sizeof(brand));
    newInfo->model = malloc (sizeof(model));

    if (!newInfo)
    {
        printf("createCarinfo: error: no space left\n");
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(newInfo->brand, brand);
        strcpy(newInfo->model, model);
        newInfo->year = year;
        newInfo->value = value;
        newInfo->next = NULL;
    }
    return newInfo;
}
```

The free function:

```
void freeCarinfo(struct carinfo_t *carinfo)
{
    if(carinfo->brand != 0)
    {
        free(carinfo->brand);
        carinfo->brand = 0;
    }
    if(carinfo->model != 0)
    {
        free(carinfo->model);
        carinfo->model = 0;
    }
    if(carinfo != 0)
    {
       free(carinfo);
       carinfo = 0;
    }
}
```

And freeCarinfo() is called by my removeCarinfo() function which basically makes sure that all the items in the queue are then properly matched when I remove the items that I seek.

What I want to do now, is to be able to free the memory that I have given the program with

```
carinfo_t *newInfo = (carinfo_t *) malloc (sizeof(newInfo));
newInfo->brand = malloc (sizeof(brand));
newInfo->model = malloc (sizeof(model));
```

Comment: `sizeof(brand)`  does not do what you expect. `brand` is a pointer, so you get the size of a pointer, 4 or 8.

Comment: `newInfo = malloc (sizeof(newInfo));` is broken. `newInfo` is a pointer.

Comment: To get the length of a "string" use `strlen()`. Also note that a C-string always needs one byte more then its maximum length. This is to store the string's end-marker, the `0`-terminator.

Comment: Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, when you're allocating space for data, you're making a common mistake:

```
newInfo->brand = malloc (sizeof(brand));
```

This allocates enough space to store a pointer to `char`, not the data itself. Then you try to copy data into it:

```
strcpy(newInfo->brand, brand);
```

which may well write more data in than you have created space for.

What you need is to create enough space for the whole string, plus the `\0` end-of-string marker:

```
newInfo->brand = malloc (strlen(brand) + 1);
```

And you'll want this as well somewhere:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Secondly, when you compare a pointer to `0`, the traditional C way is to use `NULL` rather than `0` (or not at all). It's (mostly) the same effect, but it's clearer that you're doing pointer comparisons.

Thirdly, in `freeCarinfo` you use `carinfo` and then test whether it is `NULL` (`0`). You really, really need to know whether the function can be called with the value `NULL` in which case you most not use `carinfo->brand`, or whether it is definitely not `NULL` in which case you don't need the last test.

Fourthly, as mentioned by others elsewhere, you're allocating `newInfo` in a way which doesn't give it the right amount of space:

```
carinfo_t *newInfo = (carinfo_t *) malloc (sizeof(newInfo));
```

What you probably need instead is:

```
carinfo_t *newInfo = malloc (sizeof(carinfo_t));
```

or even better:

```
carinfo_t *newInfo = malloc (sizeof(*newInfo));
```

In summary, there's lots and lots wrong here, which is why you're finding it so frustrating. Have a reread about pointers and dynamic allocation, and have another look at your code based on what you're learned.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for losing that cast for me!

Comment: Thanks a ton. I tried using strlen() before but it yielded in the same mistake. Probably due to the fact that I had no clue that I didnt allocate data correctly for newInfo.
Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. You're absolutely going in the right direction. What you're aiming for is tough, but very much worth doing. Keep going and you'll get there!

Comment: Comparing a pointer to an integer constant with value `0` means *exactly* the same thing as does comparing a pointer to `NULL`.  Both are comparisons with null pointer constants.  If one of those were considered more *traditional* than the other, it would certainly be to use `0`.  On the other hand, there is a good argument to be made for preferring use of `NULL` on stylistic grounds.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yup, when I was writing that I was aware of the places where `NULL` and `0` aren't the same, but lost that as I edited it. Thanks for that. And as far as I'm concerned, if K&R v1 uses `NULL` in pointer comparisons (and [it does](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/page/n109)), it's tough to say `0` is more traditional. Shall we compromise on "using `NULL` for pointers over `0` is best current practice"?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the return values of your `sizeof()` operators. I think you'll find that you're allocating enough bytes to store *pointers*, not the structs or characters themselves. `sizeof()` is tricky that way.

`malloc()` implementations may very well allocate some extra bytes for internal housekeeping. If you allocate too little memory, and start writing over those internal structs, you're squarely into undefined behaviour territory, and this shows when you attempt to `free()` that block, because `free()` will probably want to use that data.

Edit: See discussion below for idiomatic solution and discussion from @David Bowling to which I defer: `carinfo_t *newInfo = malloc (sizeof *newInfo);`

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator and not a macro nor a function. So those parenthesis `()`  are not part of it, nor needed when applying it to a variable.

Comment: `sizeof` is not a macro.

Comment: You're right, alk and melpomene, that was sloppy of me. Edited. However, that did not invalidate my answer in practice, and I stand by the essence of it.

Comment: The tricky bits about `sizeof` have to do with the fact that it is neither a macro nor a function, but is an operator that usually yields its result at compile time, but occasionally is instead evaluated at runtime, and usually (but not always) does not evaluate its operand. The parentheses are not part of the `sizeof` operator, but part of the operand which is an expression that may be a parenthesized type. You have the essence of a problem that OP is having, for which there is an idiomatic solution: `carinfo_t *newInfo = malloc (sizeof *newInfo);`.

Comment: Thanks, @David Bowling, for that enlightenment. I've been working around sizeof's perceived trickyness for years by making sure to only ever pass types to it, which means that code would not adapt to changes in types, e.g. of pointer variables, and which introduced bugs when I forgot to update types in both places. It looks self-evident when you write it like that, but I didn't ever see that before.

Comment: That idiom is useful because when types change during the life of a program, only the type on the left needs to be updated. So, less error-prone in program maintenance, and less error-prone in initial coding since the programmer doesn't have to juggle types. Note that here the `*newInfo` expression is not evaluated by `sizeof`, but instead the _type_ of the `*newInfo` expression is used to determine the size.